# Best way to do a web server performance comparison

Tags: linux, centos, web-server, performance

I realise this is probably very basic stuff, but I'm interested to know what you guys would recommend as the best way to recommend server performance? I have just bought a managed dedicated server but I also still have a semi dedicated server running some sites too, so I'm intrigued to see how much improvement there is. Although I expect the dedicated server performance to be better (as the semi-ded is only virtualised), how best should i go about this comparison?

Answer (score 3):

I use [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home), it's fairly simple to use but fairly powerful. To test it out just do `yum install siege` (I think it might be in the EPEL repo, alternatively just download the source and compile) then a simple test is

```
siege -c 64 -t 30s http://domain.com/
```

where -c 64 is the number of concurrent threads and -t 30s is the time to run the test for. It'll print a load of lines but at the very end you'll get some text like

```
Lifting the server siege...      done.
Transactions:               1002 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:              29.76 secs
Data transferred:           3.33 MB
Response time:              1.27 secs
Transaction rate:          33.67 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.11 MB/sec
Concurrency:               42.89
Successful transactions:        1054
/Failed transactions:              0
Longest transaction:           12.89
Shortest transaction:           0.27
```

which gives you some fairly good comparison info. The key things are `Transactions` (How many times it managed to make a connection) and `Transaction Rate` (speed of transactions). Depending on what you're testing for things like `Availability` (How many of the requests failed) may also be useful. There are quite a few options available so once you've installed just do a `siege -h` to get all the options.

Comment: out of curiousity, is there any different then apache's AB?

Comment: Not a huge difference in that basic example, but you can give siege a text file full of URLs, user agents, post data, cookies etc. so it can simulate real users on your site. I also find siege a bit easier to use and the data output is a bit easier to understand.

Comment: I should add, one important thing to remember is make sure you're not benchmarking the testing machine. I.E. make sure the machine running siege isn't on 100% CPU, has a good chunk of free RAM and has a low-ish load

Answer (score 1):

While it is a little bit older, how about httperf from HP Labs?

http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some windows based performance test tools for web servers, I would like to suggest you try [WCAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog)